# Build Errors when Compiling an APK "Failed to re-package resources

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I attempt to build an APK I get these errors.
I've tried looking for info but haven't found any solutions.

Error 1:
https://pastebin.com/Fi7mpbsQ

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android SDK\build-tools\26.0.0\aapt.exe package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J "gen" -M "AndroidManifest.xml" -S "res" -I
```

rest is on pastebin

Error 2:
https://pastebin.com/GLWnZJdz

```
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: Build failed with errors.
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x001b9] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:162 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (Boolean askForBuildLocation, BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00050] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:83 
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

Comment: Are you using any 3rd party plugins like Google Play service or facebook sdk or admob etc?

Comment: @ZayedUpal Yes I'm using Chartboost

Comment: Please try updating the Android SDK. This looks like a common problem of Unity 2017.
Please check here: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1380921/build-failed-with-errors-at-unityeditorbuildplayer.html?page=1&pageSize=5&sort=votes
and here: https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/build-and-run-fails-with-unityeditor-dot-buildplayerwindow-plus-buildmethodexception-error-on-personal-edition

Comment: @ZayedUpal I downloaded android studio and ran the update command with the tools in the tools folder.

How can I verify the update worked?

Comment: open the SDK Manager from Android Studio, click Tools > Android > SDK Manager or click SDK Manager in the toolbar. You can check the updates and installs there.

Comment: @ZayedUpalI 
Here's what I have now after I installed some sdk Tools and checked for updates

Comment: @ZayedUpal
Here's the screenshots from SDK Manager:

http://imgur.com/a/ujwrd

I still get errors in unity after this.

Comment: Everything seems okay. So, it looks like the Unity bug.

Comment: @ZayedUpal 
These are the 2 Errors I'm getting now:
https://pastebin.com/5BqTqLuk
I've changed the version to 15 and 16 in the android manifest xml and it didn't fix it.